# How to emit and listen event between pagemod and widget?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the addon-sdk. I have a widget and upon clicking the widget I want to do something with the website (be it modifying the page or reading the deep DOM).

So my thought after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts would be:

1. pagemod activated on matched url (in this case ANY)
2. click on widget which satisfies `left-click` event. It then emits `widget-click`.
3. Pagemod receives `widget-click` event and fires back an event called `from-pagemod`.
4. `from-pagemod` does something to the webpage.

I see the following output in stdout:

```
console.log: project: about to emit widget-click
console.log: project: after emitting widget-click
```

So pagemod didn't receive that event or it was never set up. I am not sure what is missing from this simple test case. Any help is appreciated.

Here is `lib/main.js`.

```
var widgets = require('sdk/widget');
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

exports.main = function() {
    var widget = widgets.Widget({
        label: "widget label",
        id: "widget-id",
        contentURL: data.url("off.png"),
        contentScriptFile: [data.url("widget.js"), data.url("page.js")]
    });

    widget.port.on("left-click", function() {
        console.log("about to emit widget-click");
        widget.port.emit("widget-click", "foo");
        console.log("after emitting widget-click");
    });


    var page = pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "*",
        contentScriptWhen: "end",
        contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js"),
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            worker.port.on("widget-click", function(msg) {
                console.log("on widget-click, ready to emit from-pagemod event");
                worker.port.emit("from-pagemod", "foo");
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Here is `page.js`

```
self.port.on("from-pagemod", function(msg) {
    console.log("inside from-pagemod listener");
    // read DOM or modify the DOM
});
```

Here is `widget.js`

```
this.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(event.button == 0 && event.shiftKey == false)
    self.port.emit('left-click');
}, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit 2, Answering the actual question:

If you want to do something to the page on widget click when the content script is already attached, register your `widget` listener somewhere you have access to the `page-worker`. You could do this by putting your `widget.port.on` code inside the `pageMod`'s `onAttach()`, but then it would only work for the most recently attached page. The best way to make it functional would be to store all workers then check if the current tab has a worker when the widget is clicked, like so:

**main.js** <sup>partial</sup>

```
var workers = [];

widget.port.on("left-click", function() {
  console.log("about to emit widget-click");
  var worker = getWorker(tabs.activeTab);
  if (worker) {
    worker.port.emit("widget-click", "foo");
    console.log("after emitting widget-click");
  }
});

var page = pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*", // TODO: make more specific
  contentScriptWhen: "end",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    workers.push(worker);
    worker.on('detach', function() {
      detachWorker(worker);
    });
    // could be written as
    // worker.on('detach', detachWorker.bind(null, worker);
  }
});

function detachWorker(worker) {
  var index = workers.indexOf(worker);
  if(index!==-1) workerArray.splice(index, 1);
}

function getWorker(workers, tab) {
  for (var i = workers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (workers[i].tab===tab) return worker;
  }
}
```

**page.js**

```
self.port.on("widget-click", function(msg) {
  console.log("inside widget-click listener");
  // read DOM or modify the DOM
});
```

The reason that your solution wasn't working is that you assumed that events were somehow linked to the file rather than an object.

---

Old answer: You're making it way too complicated.

Just attach the content script on click (as opposed to adding a content script to every single page that does nothing unless it receives an event)

### main.js

```
var widgets = require('sdk/widget');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

exports.main = function() {
    var widget = widgets.Widget({
        label: "widget label",
        id: "widget-id",
        contentURL: data.url("off.png"),
        contentScriptFile: data.url("widget.js")
    });

    widget.port.on("left-click", function() {
        console.log("about to attach script");
        var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js");
        });
        worker.port.on('message from content script', function(someVariable){
            //Now I can do something with someVariable in main.js
        });
    });
};
```

### page.js

```
// read DOM or modify the DOM
//I'm done, I'll send info back to the main script. This is optional
self.port.emit('message from content script', someVariable);
```

Edit: Read [Modifying the Page Hosted by a Tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_the_Page_Hosted_by_a_Tab) for more info. Also, the [Tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials) page is a good place to start when you're trying to do something you haven't done before with the SDK. It's a good way to step back and think of alternatives for trying to achieve your goal.

Comment: This answer would be better if you also showed the source of widget.js

Comment: @willlma Hi, thanks. But wasn't the purpose of pagemod is to run content scripts matches certain URL? In my example I did use ``*`` but in reality I could have multiple pagemods each matching different urls, right? In that case, what needs to be done?

Comment: In my experience, you either add content scripts to a page based on its URL or based on user input. What is your use case that you would need to do both?

Comment: @derman-henson I updated the answer to reflect what you're asking. Please mark it as correct if it is. Still interested in knowing your use case.

Answer (score 1):

a `port` is a communication channel between a content script and an add-on component: your Widget may interact with its content via widget.js, and your pagemod with the matched webpage content via page.js. When you do `widget.port.emit("widget-click", "foo");` this message can only be listened by `widget.js` using `self.port.on('widget-click')` not by the pagemod instance. Since you widget and pagemod are objects that share the main.js scope they can talk each other by just accessing its properties and methods.